# Ubuntu : update openssh from 4.7 to a newer version?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a server running on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS.

This version provides openssh 4.7.

I need to have a chroot environment for sftp.

I read chroot was possible with at least openssh 4.9.

So, how do I update easily to a newer version of openssh?

I specify its a remote server. So i can take the risk to damage the ssh server.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer to this is: Upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu. According to the [online Ubuntu packages database](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssh-server), the version of `openssh-server` you need is in the Jaunty and later releases.

Comment: Is it possible to just upgrade openssh without upgrading the distrib?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do this by adding an entry to `/etc/apt/sources.list` for an Ubuntu repository that contains the desired version of `openssh-server`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm gonna try this. Keep you in touch

Comment: Excuse me, what is the repository to add to sources.list to enable a 5.x openssh version ? I'm a little bit confused :?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this page http://www.minstrel.org.uk/papers/ describes a process for old versions of OpenSSH. This other site http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/creating-chroot-sftp-jails-jailkit describes another approach.

Google is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

I use [MySecureShell](http://mysecureshell.sourceforge.net/) on my Ubuntu Hardy servers to provide that same functionality.