# Update openssh from 4.7 to 5.X on Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

For some reason i can't update ubuntu to a newer version.

So I am forced to use Ubuntu 8.04.

How can I update only openssh from a 4.7 to a 5.X version ?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you update Ubuntu to a newer version?  BTW, why are you asking the same question a second time?  Why not update your existing question to make it better and have more details?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu : update openssh from 4.7 to a newer version ?](http://serverfault.com/questions/193144/ubuntu-update-openssh-from-4-7-to-a-newer-version)

Comment: Hello, I didnt get any answer on my previous question.

Comment: And i can't update because my hoster, doesn't handle specific tools for a new version of the kernel. So for the moment, i have to stay with 8.04...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download OpenSSH source. configure it to install to some private directory:

```
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ssh && make && make install
```

Now prepend /usr/local/ssh/sbin and /usr/local/ssh/bin in your $PATH. Now when you call ssh, you run the new binary.

Disable sshd in the box (I do not know whether sshd in Ubuntu 8.04 uses upstart or the older rc.* method).  Then start (the new) sshd from /etc/rc.local (in case you want the machine to run the latest sshd).